# How to know which extension provides what snippets in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed many code snippet extensions in my Visual Stuidio Code, but when I considered to use them, I got several snippets choices with a same input. I cannot tell which one should I use.

Now I have to disable some extensions. How can I find out what extensions that each snippet is provided by? or what snippets an extension is providing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a code snippet, and the extension name is showed in the hint window near the auto completing window.

[image]

Comment: Some of them don't. E.g., the "javadoc comment" triggered using "/**".